# Mean of an array excluding certain columns IDL

Tags: arrays, idl-programming-language

Hi I'm trying to write simple for loop with if loop to only calculate the mean of an array column wise (so i end up with just one row array as a mean), except column number 1051 and 1552. Here the input array has 2151 columns and 12 rows. The result in mean array should be 2149 columns and 12 rows. Here is the code I wrote

```
function specmeanex, a
  m=make_array(2151,1)
  for i=0,2150,1 do begin
    if (i ne 1051) or (i ne 1552) then begin
      m[i,0]=mean(a[i,*])
    endif
  endfor
  plot,m
  return,m
end
```

How can i either assign the empty spaces to 0 using an else? Can anyone please help me out here since I'm quite new to IDL

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an else clause like this:

```
if (i ne 1051) or (i ne 1552) then begin
  m[i,0]=mean(a[i,*])
endif else m[i,0] = 0.0
```

But, I recommend changing the code a bit to remove the `for` loop. IDL can be very efficient in vectorized operations that operate on arrays all in one statement, but slow when looping over elements of an array. Here, you are looping over the columns, which is not so bad, but could be made more IDL-like.

Try this code:

```
function mg_column_mean_exclude, a, exclude_columns
  compile_opt strictarr

  m = mean(a, dimension=2)
  m[exclude_columns] = 0.0

  return, m
end
```

Then you can call it similar to your previous routine, except you would pass in the excluded columns too:

```
m = mg_column_mean(a, [1051, 1552])
```